# App restrict in android MDM

Tags: android, admin, policy, mdm

How can I restrict the android application installed in device using the MDM? Guide me to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define MDM, are you talking API or an App?

Comment: MDM-Mobile Device Management. I am talking about the API. For example If user having gtalk installed in the device, when he try to open the app I need to restrict it. For reference Mass360 app:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fiberlink.maas360.android.control

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what the Mass360 app does under the hood, there is a Device Admin API that became available in 2.2.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score -1):

You will either need to write your application with Root permissions enabled, which will allow you to control the device a little more, or you will have to do some trickery to register yourself with the device when applications are launched. I am not even sure if the latter is possible, so I would advise you look down the Root path. I am afraid I cannot post any code samples as I have not done this before.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Any update let it know. I will try with your idea. Thanks lot!!