# Disable USB transfer from code Android

Tags: android

I need lock the usb data transfer,  from my android application, exists a form to make this in a no rooted device?

Comment: With "usb data transfer" you mean accessing the devices SD-Card on a computer? For what purpose do you need it?

Comment: Yes, too many people will use the tablet, and we need prevent that they can copy or add files to the sd card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android 2.2, you can use the [Device Administrator API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) to control the access of the user through an Administrator.

This API exposes a [`setStorageEncryption()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setStorageEncryption%28android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean%29), which will encrypt the application-data sections of the internal storage.

For external storage's (such as SD-cards), there can't be any real "restrictions", as the user can easily pull the SD-Card out of the device and plug it into a PC manually.

A problem which might persist is, that the user can still install a file-manager, allowing him to send files to a pc/to the tablet by using Bluetooth for example. This problem can not be completely eliminated, as there is no good way of preventing a user from installing applications from the Android Market.

However, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376570/is-there-a-way-to-stop-preventing-users-from-installing-android-apps), pulling the Android sources and building your own version of the OS might work fine, although it is extremely costly.

The other idea to tackle this problem would be to root the device, which would give you more power over such things (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771995/app-restrict-in-android-mdm)).